# In Python libtorrent, what is the exception type throw when error occurs in session seeding?

Tags: python, libtorrent

I wanna catch some exception if the session met some error on seeding phase. 
But it is a python-binding of C++ library, I don't know where I can find the document to list python exception type. I try:

```
 import libtorret 
 help(libtorrent)
```

and it does not provide about exception information. Does anyone provide a document location about python-libtorrent exception list or what exception will throw at this case?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the exception information in the libtorrent library documentation: http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#exceptions